# race condition on passing multiple parameter into URL in Django templates

Tags: django-views, django-templates, django-urls, race-condition, url-parameters

views

```
def increase_att(request,student_id ,sub):
    print(sub)
    print(subject)
    t = StudentInfo.objects.get(id=student_id)
    t.sub1_att = F('sub1_att')+1
    t.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('count?subject=Python')
```

template

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h1>Attendance Count</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form action="" method="GET">
                    Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% if student_list_sub1 %} <!-- for 1st subject--> 
    <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Admission ID</th>
            <th>{% for std_list in student_list_sub1 %}
                {{std_list.sub1}} 
                {% endfor %} Attendance</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        {% for std_list in student_list_sub1 %}
            <tr>
                <td class="cls_name">{{ std_list.name }}</td>
                <td class="cls_admission">{{ std_list.usn }}</td>
                <td class="cls_class">{{ std_list.sub1_att }}%</td>
                <td><button type="submit" onclick="location.href='{% url 'increase_att' std_list.id std_list.sub1 %}'">Present</button> <button class="count_btn">Absent</button></td>
                
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
path('attendance/<student_id>/<sub>',views.increase_att,name='increase_att'),
```

with single parameter "student_id" the program works fine i.e
on pressing the button(Present) the attendence increments.But on passing multiple values like "student_id" AND "sub" it faces race condition.

models.py

````
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    admission_date = models.DateField()
    usn = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sub1 = models.ForeignKey(StudentSubjectInfo,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='sub1',null=True)
    sub1_att = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
    sub2 = models.ForeignKey(StudentSubjectInfo,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='sub2',null=True)
    sub2_att = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)```

i have put subject name and its attendance for each students.
Upon displaying the list of students i have also put a button to each student upon pressing that button "increase_att" should be called and attendance of that student(student_id) in that particular subject(sub) must be incremented.
````

Comment: if i may ask what is the use of the sub augment  that you pass to increase_att ,if you an add your model.py  i think might be able to help ?

Comment: in order to increment the attendance of a student,my view (increase_att) must know which student using "student_id" and which subject using "sub".

Comment: When i type subject name (Python) into input and press submit button i can see following "http://localhost:8000/students/attendance/count/?subject=Python"  I want to get that subject value from the url into the increase_att views

Comment: I can only help you if you share the model of your app on here, the link won't work because its on  your localhost of you machine.

Comment: I have put the StudentsInfo model pls let me know if u want anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit there's so much irregularities in your code, this is what i have tried to come up with to help you in the right direction. I nearly lost my mind reading your code. but i hope this leads to a solution. Your  return HttpResponseRedirect('count?subject=Python') is something else. i think you should refactor your code for clarity, that way others will be able to help. but i hope this lead to your solution

```
def increase_att(request,student_id):
    # This where we get the id of the student 
    student = get_object_or_404(StudentInfo,id=student_id)
    # Am assuming if you have a model for subject
    # Here we are filtering subject by student id 
    subject = StudentSubjectInfo.objects.filter(id=student.id)
    # Since you don't have an subject attendance form am assuming 
    # But you sure have to create a form to handle your attendance 
    form = AttentanceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       sub1_att_data = form.save(commit=False)
       sub1_att_data.sub = subject # here you are getting the sub id to save
       sub1_att_data.student = student.id # we are getting the student id to save in the form
       # Basically this to give you an idea on how to make you view work inorder to save data 
      sub1_att_data.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('count?subject=Python')
```